# python get new windows processes ids as they start running in an event

Tags: python, process, ctypes

Im looking for a way to get new processes ids as they start running.
currently i could get list of processes like this:

```
from ctypes import *

psapi = windll.psapi

print "[+] PID dumper by Y"
print "[+] contact : If you know me then give me a shout"

def getListOfProcesses():
    max_array = c_ulong * 4096 # define long array to capture all the processes
    pProcessIds = max_array() # array to store the list of processes
    pBytesReturned = c_ulong() # the number of bytes returned in the array
    #EnumProcess 
    psapi.EnumProcesses(byref(pProcessIds),
                        sizeof(pProcessIds),
                        byref(pBytesReturned))

    # get the number of returned processes
    nReturned = pBytesReturned.value/sizeof(c_ulong())
    pidProcessArray = [i for i in pProcessIds][:nReturned]
    for processes in pidProcessArray:
        print "[+] Running Process PID %d" % processes 

getListOfProcesses()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18302483/205580.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [WMI module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html):

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
process_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")

while True:
    p = process_watcher()
    print "[+] Running Process PID %d" % p.ProcessId
```

By the way, in your `getListOfProcesses` function you can use `pProcessIds[:nReturned]` instead of the list comprehension.